# Applying different css styles to text

Tags: html, css

I have a `<table>`, with some text in it:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <b>Title</b>
      <br />
      Some description text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This works great, except now I want to give the title and the description different text colors. I want to maintain their current spacing though, otherwise I would do this:

```
<td>
  <p class="title">Title</p>
  <p class="desc">Some description text</p>
</td>
```

Using a "< p >" element seems to inject a tall new line, instead of the nicer "< br />" (well at least nicer in my opinion). But if I don't use a "p", I'm not sure how to apply different styles to either piece of text.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following style to your p tags:

**css**

```
p {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

**html**

```
<td>
    <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
    <p class="desc">Some description text</p>
</td>
```

Comment: I would like to add that its better to use a <h1> tag or similar for a title and <p> for a paragraph rather than making a <p> tag look like a title.

Comment: Definitely agree with @MatthewGreen, that is proper use of the h1 tag (a heading)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
td {
  color: orange;
}

td b {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Using a "< p >" element seems to inject a tall new line, instead of the nicer "< br />" (well at least nicer in my opinion)

No it isn't nicer in anyones opinion.

Just style the `p` how you would like it to be presented, e.g.:

```
p { margin-bottom: 0; }
```

Also it looks like you not using tables for tabular data, but rather for layout purposes which is bad m'kay.

Also even the `p` tag wouldn't be semantically correct. Use a heading tag for this.

Another advantage is that you don't have to use those ugly `b` tags. Even if you need to use `b` features you should use the `strong` element.

Answer (score 0):

The second code you show is better, because more semantically correct. Even better would be this:

```
    <td>
        <h3>Title</h3> <!-- this is a title, so mark it as one -->
        <p>Some description text</p> <!-- this is a piece of text, so mark it as one -->
    </td>
```

And use the following CSS:

```
h3,p {
    margin:0;
}
h3 {
    color:red;
}
p {
    color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give a unusual attribute, you can anything you want.

```
CSS:
        tr[unusual="1"] {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

HTML:

        <tr unusual="1">
        <td></td>
        </tr>
```